# trying to select where left join is null using doctrine query builder

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4, query-builder

I'm trying to select all Rooms that are not occupied on given Reservation dates.
I've created such code:

```
$queryBuilder->select('rm')
            ->from('App:Room', 'rm')
            ->leftJoin('App:Reservation', 'r', 'WITH', $queryBuilder->expr()->andX(
                $queryBuilder->expr()->lt('r.start', '?1'),
                $queryBuilder->expr()->gt('r.stop', '?2'),
                $queryBuilder->expr()->neq('r.status', '?3')
                )
            )->where(
                $queryBuilder->expr()->andX(
                    $queryBuilder->expr()->isNull('r')
                )
            )->setParameters(
                array(
                    1 => $stop,
                    2 => $start,
                    3 => Reservation::STATUS_EXPIRED
                )
            );
```

I have 2 reservations on 2 rooms, where room id equals reservation id:

> 1. 2000-01-01 - 2000-01-02
> 2. 2000-01-01 - 2000-01-03

Also `$start = '2000-01-02'` and `$stop = '2000-01-05'` and status of both reservations is `Reservation::STATUS_NEW`
I would expect that given these dates, this query would return me room 1., as room 2 has reservation colliding with them but the result is empty.
Removing the `where` clause results in both rooms being returned. In this case `$queryBuilder->getQuery()->getArrayResult()` returns both rooms and reservation number 2. as expected, but when I restore the `where` clause, the array is just empty.

My another approach is through a subquery but it behaves exactly the same so please advise, what am I missing?

```
$queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
        $all = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

        $all->select('rma.id')
            ->from('App:Room', 'rma')
            ->innerJoin('App:Reservation', 'r')
            ->where(
                $all->expr()->andX(
                    $all->expr()->lt('r.start', '?1'),
                    $all->expr()->gt('r.stop', '?2'),
                    $all->expr()->neq('r.status', '?3')
                )
            );

        $queryBuilder->select('rm')
            ->from('App:Room', 'rm')
            ->where(
                $queryBuilder->expr()->neq(
                    'rm.id',
                    $queryBuilder->expr()->all(
                        $all->getDQL()
                    )
                )
            )->setParameters(
                array(
                    1 => $stop,
                    2 => $start,
                    3 => Reservation::STATUS_EXPIRED
                )
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would want to exclude rooms, where the reservations have *overlap* with the query date span.

that is

```
$queryBuilder->expr()->lt('r.start', '?1'), // 1 being stop
$queryBuilder->expr()->gt('r.stop', '?2'),  // 2 being start
```

which you already had correct. however, your null check is off, it should be:

```
$queryBuilder->expr()->isNull('r') // <-- you had rm here
```

so, `r` is obviously the reservation, and that one should be null ("missing").

(I always find that using short aliases makes it really really hard to spot those kinds of errors, and it's so little actual time saved ..., I also much prefer named parameters over numbered parameters)

**update**

Okay, I missed the main point being wrong here ;o/

your query matches all rooms with **all** reservations (not just the reservations of that room), and selects those, that "have" no reservation. Meaning: if there is a reservation for the date span, you get back NO rooms, and if there is no reservation for the date span, you get back ALL rooms.

There's two ways to make the querybuilder do the right thing, which depends on your mapping definition, but I will assume, that the `Room` entity has a field `reservations` that holds all reservations for that room.

```
$qb->from('Room', 'rm')
   ->leftJoin('rm.reservations', 'r', 'WITH', ...)
```

The difference being, that the "table" descriptor *implies* that the reservations are of the respective room and only joined with those.

Or being explicit:

```
$qb->from('Room', 'rm')
   ->leftJoin('Reservation', 'r', 'WITH', $qb->expr()->andX('r.room=rm', ...))
```

That should finally solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems on first look that you are right. I'll try it when I get home and mark your answer as solution if that's all.
Second it more complicated approach and I'm affraid I just missunderstood how expressions work (also aliases are messed up, because I messed with entity structure around a lot ^^')

Comment: tbh, I don't particularly like the `expr()` stuff anyway. I believe there is nothing significant to be gained over DQL, in like ... 99% of use cases.

Comment: Personally, I find queryBuilder more readable than pure DQL, especially when you build queries dynamically based on many different conditions.

Comment: Oh I don't write pure DQL, I just avoid the `expr()` stuff. I don't see how `andWhere($qb->expr()->isNull('reservation'))` is better in any way then just `andWhere('reservation IS NULL')`. I really like the fact, that with the querybuilder one can neglect the order in which to add stuff, so query generation is really clear in code (obviously not necessarily, but can be done that way)

Comment: Unfortunately it turned out that the "rm" was just an editing mistake. In my original code I have "r" (I have different alias, but it stands for reservation) and it still return no rooms at all.

Comment: @ArkadiuszGaller okay, it's pretty hard to find error in source code that is actually not an identical copy of the code that shows the faulty behaviour. for example, if the original uses `innerJoin` except of `leftJoin` could very well be a reason. Would you please check, that you have an identical copy and modify your original post?

Comment: I updated the question and my code to match EXACTLY original code.

Comment: @ArkadiuszGaller okay, I missed the real problem. updated the answer.

Comment: It's strange to me as to my best knowledge Doctrine manages relations by itself (reservations to rooms is a ManyToMany relations, so in fact the join goes through another table) and the distinction between "WITH" and "ON" is that "WITH" adds given constraints to join constraint and "ON" replaces original join constraint. So does Doctrine not manage relation by itself? What's the difference between "WITH" and "ON" then?

Comment: oh you are right to *some* extent. the "with" says, I want the standard join condition plus the following. however, just saying "i want to join room and reservation" in itself doesn't say, room.reservations is THE join condition by default. I mean, you could say different things. in fact, the standard join condition is just ... "true", which joins everything with everything. also, **all** examples on https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html show how to do joins with `u.Group` and not just `Group`. so ... not much is assumed.

Comment: Thank you for your time and engagement. Proper solution is in my post but it's thanks to you that I finally got to it so I've marked your answer as solution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above placed me on the right track to understand my failure.
My final code looks like this:

```
$queryBuilder->select('rm')
            ->from('App:Room', 'rm')
            ->leftJoin('rm.reservations', 'r', 'WITH', $queryBuilder->expr()->andX(
                $queryBuilder->expr()->lt('r.start', '?1'),
                $queryBuilder->expr()->gt('r.stop', '?2'),
                $queryBuilder->expr()->neq('r.status', '?3')
                )
            )->where(
                $queryBuilder->expr()->andX(
                    $queryBuilder->expr()->isNull('r')
                )
            )->setParameters(
                array(
                    1 => $stop,
                    2 => $start,
                    3 => Reservation::STATUS_EXPIRED
                )
            );
```

It was all about joining `rm.reservations`, not general `App:Reservation` as I did. Assocations are well defined inside Entity classes and Doctrine will add proper constraints if I point to field of the object instead of general class.
Example given by Jakumi would work ok for a ManyToOne assocation, in my case (ManyToMany) I would have to manually join the joining table between Reservation and Room.

Comment: no, actually, this works for many-to-many as well. ;o) (unless your many-to-many is manifested as its own entity with two many-to-one/one-to-many relations)

Comment: I mean I couldn't do just r.room = rm, beacuse there is no "room" field in the Reservation entity. There is "rooms" field and also "reservations" field in the Room entity. Maybe there is a way to make the join this way but I don't see how ^^'

Comment: I agree that it's unclear what `r.rooms = rm` would/could even mean, `rm IN r.rooms` could probably work though. But yeah, many-to-many can require a bit more effort.